# Array in c, char type

Tags: c, arrays, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
char c[10];
int k=0;
printf("please enter the element value in character\n");
for(k=0;k<10;k++)
{     
scanf("%c",&c[k]);
}
for(k=0;k<10;k++)
{
printf("Value in char is %c\n",c[k]);
}
return 0;
}
```

//problem is that i can only initialize value of 5 char not 10.
My IDE is code::blocks with GNU GCC COMPILER .

Comment: Please try `scanf(" %c",&c[k]);` notice the added space.

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: @pm100 the loop stops after 5 inputs instead of 10 as stated.

Comment: @WeatherVane didn't work

Comment: To add to what @WeatherVane said: some of the characters you obtained are `\n` (the ENTERs).

Comment: @Maddy *what* "does not work". I amended your program and it accepts and then prints 10 inputs.

Comment: it is spiking every other scanf or in other words  scanf is being called twice everytime idk why

Comment: So you can't have added that space.

Comment: Try inputting all in a row: `"elevendigitENTER"` or `"9876543210ENTER"`.

Comment: Or, think of `a<Enter>b<Enter>c<Enter>...` 6 characters so far.

Comment: scanf(" %c*c",&c[k]) this worked

Comment: do you mean the loop stops inputting or it stops outputting?

Comment: it stop inputting after initializing 5 char.

Comment: I have a question is scanf also grabbing enter as a char ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scanf("%c%*c");` to read the newline after your character.  The %*c matches a single character, but the asterisk indicates that the character will not be stored anywhere. This has the effect of consuming the newline character generated by the enter key so that the next time you call scanf() you are starting with an empty input buffer.

Comment: thanks,but can u explain ?

Comment: Each `scanf("%c")` call reads just on character and leaves the newline character stuck in the stdin buffer.  You need to consume that character before calling `scanf(...)` a second time or it will return the newline character '\n',

Answer (score 0):

When you press enter from your keyboard, the program reads the char you have just entered (e.g 'a')  along with a new-line character("\n") from pressing the enter button. You must handle this in your code by writing your scanf the following way: scanf(" %c" , &c[k]) . There must be a whitespace before the %c. This tells the compiler to ignore all whitespace characters.